# Pivotal Quantity of a Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics

Assuming that $X_1,...,X_n i.i.d \sim $ Normal($\mu, \sigma^2$)

How do you find a pivotal quantity $h(X_1,...,X_n;\mu)$ that can be used to find a confidence interval for $\mu$, assuming that $\sigma^2$ is unknown?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity#Normal_distribution

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241855/confidence-intervals-distribution-of-a-pivot/2241914#2241914

Answer (score 2):

By a pivotal quantity it is usually meant a random variable whose distribution does not depend on unknown parameters. To give an example, if $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables with $X_i \sim \mathcal{N} \left(\mu, \sigma^2\right)$ where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown, using the sample standard deviation $S$ it is well-known that the random variable

$$Y = \frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{S/ \sqrt{n}}$$

has the t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. Based on this, a confidence interval for $\mu$ may be constructed.